# Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I am deploying my ruby on rails application to DigitalOcean Ubuntu server. But I got this `Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded.` error.

**Here is the full error:**

[image]

**Here is my Gemfile.lock:**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.3)
      actionpack (= 4.2.3)
      actionview (= 4.2.3)
      activejob (= 4.2.3)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.3)
      actionview (= 4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.3)
      activemodel (= 4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.3)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.3)
    autoprefixer-rails (6.0.3)
      execjs
      json
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    better_errors (2.1.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.4.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.0.0.1)
      sass (>= 3.2.19)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (6.0.2)
    capistrano (3.4.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.3)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano3-puma (1.2.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      puma (>= 2.6)
    choice (0.2.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    colorize (0.7.7)
    daemons (1.2.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.5.2)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.8)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    font-awesome-rails (4.4.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    haml (4.0.7)
      tilt
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.5)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.3)
    kaminari (0.16.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.6.2)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.8.1)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    mysql2 (0.3.20)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (3.0.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    puma (2.14.0)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-pjax (0.8.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (~> 1.1)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.3)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.3)
      actionpack (= 4.2.3)
      actionview (= 4.2.3)
      activejob (= 4.2.3)
      activemodel (= 4.2.3)
      activerecord (= 4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.3)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-erd (1.4.3)
      activerecord (>= 3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
      choice (~> 0.2.0)
      ruby-graphviz (~> 1.2)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_admin (0.6.8)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0)
      font-awesome-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      haml (~> 4.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.14)
      nested_form (~> 0.3)
      rack-pjax (~> 0.7)
      rails (~> 4.0)
      remotipart (~> 1.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
      sass-rails (>= 4.0, < 6)
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.4)
    railties (4.2.3)
      actionpack (= 4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    remotipart (1.2.1)
    responders (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5)
    ruby-graphviz (1.2.2)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    sass (3.4.18)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    sprockets (3.3.5)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sshkit (1.7.1)
      colorize (>= 0.7.0)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    thin (1.6.4)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2015.7)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.2.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  better_errors
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3.4.1)
  byebug
  capistrano
  capistrano-bundler
  capistrano-rails
  capistrano-rvm
  capistrano3-puma
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  devise
  execjs
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.18)
  puma
  rails (= 4.2.3)
  rails-erd
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
  rails_admin (~> 0.6.8)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  therubyracer
  thin
  turbolinks
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)
```

I have already specified `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'` in my Gemfile on so I don't know what other solution that I could use to fix this.

Please help. Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: @Pavan Yeah, of course. I have specified it and also have run bundle install.

Comment: Could you please publish your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: @TheAncient Ok, I have put it on my question. Please check it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Try to ssh to your server, clone project repo somewhere in /tmp, run bundle install manually from there. Then try capistrano again. BTW, are you using rbenv/rvm or something else to manage rubies?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind so far, is that you apparently bundl'ed it on windows (indicated by the platform statement in Gemfile.lock), but deploy on Linux. I'm not sure about Digital Ocean, but OpenShift still has a problem, that gems, having mingw platform in Gemfile.lock metadata, are not installed. An important point here is how the deployment works -- based on Gemfile (runs bundle install right in place) or uses Gemfile.lock. If the latter is the case, try to replace "x86-mingw32" platform with "ruby". BTW, do you have deployment logs to share?

Comment: Hey, I just fixed it! It looks like i need to push update to my repository on Github first before deploying it to the server :) Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it.

Actually, after added `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'` , I need to push it to my repository on Github first before deploying it to the server.